# How to convert UTC date to datetime type Laravel?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have UTC time as: `2021-01-30T21:00:00.000Z`

How to convert it to datetime type for adding to database using Carbon?

I have tried this:

```
Carbon::now(new Date("2021-01-30T21:00:00.000Z"))->format("yyyy-dd-mm");
```

Comment: "I have tried this" but_why.gif

Comment: `Carbon::now()` will obviously return *now*. Try perhaps `Carbon::create()` or `new Carbon` instead. See docs here: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation

Comment: `create()` and next?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to, which provides many examples for different ways to create Carbon objects.

Comment: Try this `Carbon::parse('2021-01-30T21:00:00.000Z')->format('yyyy-dd-mm');`

Comment: I have read there is not example with create and format

Comment: it converts to `'21212121-3030-0101'`

Comment: `'21212121-3030-0101'` is correct,  because you want  this format `yyyy-dd-mm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...`Carbon::parse('2021-01-30T21:00:00.000Z')`